# WindowsForm: working on vscrollbar vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a big Form, so I try to put vscrollbar in my form, but when i run and try slide it upside down,the form are not move. Why is it so?

Comment: I have try to set the autoscroll in form to true, but there is no scrollbar appear

Comment: Then you did it wrong. Create a new form, set its `AutoScroll` property to `True` and add two `Button` controls.  Place the first in the top, left corner and the second in the bottom, right corner.  Run the project and grab the bottom, right corner of the form and make it smaller.  You'll see scrollbars appear if and only if they are required.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow sapkoklu! There is a [tutorial here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions, and I think you might benefit from it in the future. @jmcilhinney please remember that we all started out as beginners and asked beginner questions. Have patience, please.